# Show that the roots of $x^2 − 2α x +β = 0$ are $x = α \pm \sqrt {α^2 −β}$

Tags: roots, quadratics

I have been asked to show that the roots of $$x^2-2αx+β$$ are $$x=α±\sqrt{α^2- β}$$

I do not have any idea how to complete this question, I believe factorising is involved but I don't know how to apply it if so.

I have got the steps here but I am not able to complete the square. please can someone show me? this is what I have.

[image]

Any help in terms of finding a solution and showing methodology would be very much appreciated.

Edited  let us solve this equation

$x^2+3*x-4=0$

let us calculate discriminant 
$d=b^2-4*ac=9+16=25$

$x_1=(-b+\sqrt(d))/2=(-3+5)/2=1$

$x_2=(-3-5)/2)=-4$

Comment: The equations aren't consistent in the title and body. And as for the question, look up the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Comment: @Bernard - Apparently, the title has the correct equation.

Comment: You could also apply Bhaskara's formula for the roots of quadratic equations and it would arise naturally after simplifications.

Comment: @GuilhermeK.Nakassima Is it the "$abc$-formula" ? This will of course work as well, but knowing the "$pq$"-formula or Vieta is useful here (because the leading coefficient happens to be $1$)

Comment: Complete the square

Comment: @Flewitt Connor  see my solution :)

Comment: @Peter Yes, and yours is truly far simpler. But still, it's an option.

Comment: @Flewitt Connor  dont forget also to accept  any of  answers because it is sign  that your problem is  solved

Comment: @datodatuashvili my problem is not solved as I have not been able to follow the methodology, please help

Comment: i have  updated your question  with solution , please see

Comment: @FlewittConnor Factorization is also an option. Consider the roots are $\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta}$ and $\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta}$ , so we have to show $x^2-2\alpha x+\beta=(x-\alpha-\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta})\cdot (x-\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta})$

Comment: To show that simplify the right side using $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Vieta's theorem allows a quick proof. The sum of the roots must be $2\alpha$ and the product $\beta$

Comment: If you know the "$pq$-formula", you can calculate the roots directly.

Comment: how do i find two roots that add up to 2α which also multiply to β? i dont even know where to start as they aren't even numbers. i am absolutely desperate for help all the answers here have confused me more  than anything so far

Comment: @FlewittConnor It would be helpful to know whether you know the "$pq$"-formula, or whether you want the "completing-the square" method or whether you know the theorem of Vieta. You should inform us about your knowledge, otherwise it is difficult to give an answer satisfying you. I will try to explain the probably simplest approach, although you do not need to calculate the roots because they are already given.

Comment: I think, "completing the square" is the easiest approach. We start with $$x^2-2\alpha x+\beta=0$$ Subtracting $\beta$ gives $$x^2-2\alpha=-\beta$$ To get a binomial expression (in this case of the form $(a-b)^2$), we must add $\alpha^2$. Then, we have $$x^2-2\alpha x+\alpha^2=\alpha^2-\beta$$ But the left side is $(x-\alpha)^2$, a square. Try to follow up until here and tell me whether I can continue.

Comment: I am only familiar with the quadratic formula, however I have not been able to apply it here.

 I know that I must change the form of $x^2 -2αx$ to become $(x-α)^2$ . So i have, $$(x-α)^2 = x^2-2αx+α^2$$This has given an additional $α^2$ to my expression so I must add $α^2$ to both sides, giving:$$x^2-αx+a^2 = α^2 - β$$Which is the same as$$(x-α)^2 = α^2 - β$$Then to get rid of the 2 exponent i get $$x-α =±\sqrt{α^2-β}$$Then I add α to both sides to get x on its own giving me $$x = α±\sqrt{α^2-β}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, one thing I am still uncertain about is the reason for converting to $(x-α)^2$ in the first place. I am sorry if it is a silly question to you but it would be great to fully understand the entire process.

Comment: Your steps are correct. The formula is based on the binomial expression (Therefore the name completing the square, we bring the constant to the other side and then add the crucial term to have a square). As you can see, we can finally isolate $x$ and that is what we want.

Answer (score 2):

$d=4*\alpha^2-4*\beta$

which is the same as  $4*(\alpha^2-\beta) $ square root from this will be  $2*\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta)}$

can you continue?

we will have ($2*\alpha+2*\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta)}) /2$

and
($2*\alpha-2*\sqrt{a^2-\beta)}) /2$

factorize  $2$ out of bracket

Comment: I dont know what you mean where have you gotten the d from ?

Comment: I am really stuck with this

Comment: can you solve general  quadratic equation? please solve this one $x^2+3*x-4$

Comment: $(x+4)(x-1)$ I am now going to work through your edit, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x) = x^2-2\alpha x+\beta = 0$

$f(x) = (x-\alpha)^2+\beta-\alpha^2 =0$

Then $x= \alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta}$ as required.

Comment: how have you gone from the first line to the second line?

Comment: @FlewittConnor In general $f(x)=x^2+bx+c = (x+\frac{b}{2})^2-\frac{b^2}{4}+c$ - expand it to convince yourself; note this is known as completing the square

Answer (score 1):

These are simply the so-called *reduced formulae* for quadratic equations $\;ax^2+2b'x+c=0\,$: one sets
$$\Delta'=b'^2-ac\qquad(\textit{reduced discriminant}).$$
If $\Delta'> 0$, the (real) root  are
$$x_1, x_2=\frac{-b'\pm\sqrt{\Delta'}}{a}.$$

Comment: i hope that  he/she can guess  idea :)

Comment: Well, I'm not supposed to give all details, but really it's not hard. Anyway this is standard, and every well-bred young people should know these formulae.

Comment: such kind of formulas yes, but in generally there are so  different levels at schools ,  for instance in my country ,  two or three  school are mathematical  schools, others are abandoned   and  they  dont know  many things in mathematics

Comment: I have no idea where to start with delta prime this is more confusing than the original question

Comment: Do you know the usual resolution formulae for quadratic equations? Just observe $\Delta=4\Delta'$, so in the formulae, we can factor out $2$ from both numerator and denominator.